# How to create a "waiting" queue when there are more than 2 visitors on the website

Tags: forms, checkbox, queue, visitors

Hello,
I use a form on my website. This form contains content that can only be selected once.

I would like to create some sort of "queue" when there is more than one visitor on the page.

So for example 2 visitors:
visitor 1 -> fill in the form.
visitor 2 -> gets popup with "please wait"
visitor 1 -> sends the form.
system processes data from form.
visitor 2 -> make popup invisible and show form.

Or another option would be to check if someone else has checked the checkbox yet and give a message if someone has checked this yet.

Comment: Initializing a a queue system on a form is a bad idea, like the previous answered said this is a awful user experience,can you point out why you want to put in place a queue sytem to your form, we need a context it :)

Comment: I have a licensing form where people can license artworks for specific branches, licensing that artwork is exclusive for the branche they apply for.'I don't want to get duplicate applications for the same artwork, because I need to mail people and dissapoint them and ask them to choice an X number of artworks again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you didn't provide any code I will just give you my humble thoughts on this.

First of all: May I ask why? This sounds like a horrible user experience...

If you really want to do it anyways, here's what you need: AJAX or jQuery to provide the live feedback popup you mentioned. For the visitor count caching part there are obviously many ways to do it like using scripts of any kind or even some file or database based solution. From that point on you just go with your favorite web language and code the main queue logic, I would recommend PHP with a breeze of JavaScript.

I hope this was at least a little bit helpful.

Kind regards

Comment: After reading your reasoning I get your point... Just let us know if you are stuck, I am semi-experienced with something that reassembles your use case closely. It was no private project though, so I am afraid I can't share any code.